# Working React + Typescrpt while my team is working React + Javascpript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new in React but I have a history in Angular.
So before I start working with React I have a question for you.

Whole team is working in React with Javascript and I would like to work with Typescript.
Is there any possibility to mix this?
I believe that there will be some issue with merge requests and some config typescript files but please let me know what do you think about it and is this real doable?

Thanks

Comment: even if possible, you're going to have a lot of fun resolving conflicts for your team that's for sure. as your team lead, I would not let you write part of the codebase in a different language, as good as it may be

Comment: No, its not adviceable to use typescript for parts of a project. Either convice them to switch everything to ts or learn to deal with js.

Comment: If you're used to typescript then what's wrong with developing in javascript? I think there will be a lot of issues when they try to consume the components written by you and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks guys for prompt answers. I was afraid that it would be problemous for everybody.

Comment: @RameshReddy 
well, I was working with TS and right now when I look at JS code i looks a little be poor (? I don't know how to name it) without all this typing and without all this hints in VSC
Maybe it's just my nooby thinking but we will see in few months. 
I just want to have better start in React world.

Comment: oh no, don't do that, unless the whole team has a plan to migrate from js to ts.

Comment: @Dnc I get that. If the existing app is relatively small then convert every component to `tsx`.

Comment: @RameshReddy Unfortunately is a big project. I believe I need to start some React + JS tutorials :P

Comment: @Dnc with vscode you should still be able to get some intellisense in pure JS. As others have said, bad idea to mix and match in your team. You may be able to get some middleground, have a look at this article. https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/build-100-type-safe-react-apps-in-vanilla-javascript-bd29a8364078

Comment: @mbdavis wow, thanks! did you try to work this way?

Comment: I'm going to say it depends,..  Mixing TS & JS is of course very common,.. If you look at NPM there are lots of projects written in TS, but of course are still consumed in JS.  So it really depends on what your doing,.  If it's something your doing and responsible for, and other users of your team are not meant to maintain, then they shouldn't be any issues.  But if they need to be able to maintain too, then it's a different story, as they would need to have knowledge of TS too.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, there are compile options in TS that are designed to not touch your code, and just remove the typings.  This is handy if your want the JS code to look pretty much the same as your TS code without types.  So if other users of your team do need to see the JS code, it doesn't look like garbled / obfuscated code.

Comment: @ts-ignore is your friend )

Comment: @Keith this what you talking about seems to be pretty useful do you have some link with more details?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yeah, that's a good one. also ts-nocheck
https://dev.to/evaldasburlingis/typescript-for-beginners-how-to-ignore-code-4han

Comment: @Dnc  It's basically setting the target type to esnext.  There might be some edge cases,.  But Typescript follows the ES Spec really well these days.  So doing a target of esnext pretty much remove the type information, and then this JS file just looks like a regular JS file.  As pointed out you can use Typscript with normal JS files using jsDoc comments, but I had less success.  Eg, require calls in node didn't auto complete etc.

Comment: @Keith ok, thanks for that